# send barcode number to activity dialog without black screen

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I make an app to read barcode numbers and I used a surface view with a camera source in it. The app send the value to another activity which is shown as a dialog.
I make other activity as dialog but the problem the surface view is stopped. I tried many solutions until this works which is to put these lines in onCreate method .

```
 setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);        
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**with adding these two lines in onCreate method the surface view didn't stop and it works but the problem is the dialog shown in black screen also the parent when the dialog is shown it turns all to black. how to fix this problem.**

I also modified manifest to process that and I add the following

```
 <activity android:name=".InfoActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

these the whole code of the class

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    TextView txtShow, itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity;
    TextView txtNameDialog, txtPriceDialog, txtQuantityDialog;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionId = 1001;
    String code;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionId: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        txtShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
        itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
        itemQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);

        startBarcode();

    }

    public void startBarcode() {
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(800, 600)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        //Events

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Make Request Runtime Permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionId);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Make Request Runtime Permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionId);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {

            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (qrCodes.size() != 0) {
                    txtShow.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //stop camera
                            cameraSource.stop();

                            //create vibrate
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(500);

                            //set result for Text View
                            txtShow.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                            final String code = txtShow.getText().toString();
                            // surfaceView.setTop(200);


                            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.barcode);
                            mp.start();
                            Button getInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getInfo);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InfoActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried to restart surfaceview in same activity but it didnt work